# Cant get _global variables

Tags: actionscript-2, flash, smartfoxserver

I have a code which is supposed to get two _global variables from another file. This code is loaded using loadMovieNum() function which is inside the file which contains the two _global variables. Also my swf is set to be opened with flash player 6 for various reasons. Here is my code to get variables:

```
  var serverIndddd = new LoadVars();
      var serverOutdddd = new LoadVars();
      serverOutdddd.named = _global.myName;
      serverOutdddd.money = _root.score
      serverOutdddd.sendAndLoad("addmoney.php",serverIndddd,"post");
 _root._visible = false;   
 _global.isBusy = false;
Mouse.show()
```

Here is my code to load movie:

```
    loadMovieNum("space_attack.swf", 1);
_global.isBusy = true
```

Please help!

Comment: You did not mention what actually happens and what the desired behaviour would be. What is exactly wrong?

Comment: All I can say at once is that `serverOutdddd.money = _root.score` addresses the root of *space_attack.swf*, and not of the main movie.

Comment: @NoxNoctis What happens is that the _global.myName is getting undefined, while in my main script it works.

Comment: Well, then you don't have anything relevant in the code you posted. If one builds a sample of what you describe, it will work. I did so in a couple of minutes. Provide some more detail, so the question becomes answerable. But first, place `trace()` everywhere important and see the order of execution. When `myName` gets assigned value, when the loaded swf tries to access it, etc.

Comment: I can't give more details and I already trace() everything. The value the loaded swf has is always undefined.

Comment: Look, it takes only 2 minutes to test it and it certainly works: http://dpaste.com/3W27C3R Thus the problem is outside this very code you posted, it's somewhere else. Are you sure the variable `_global.myName` gets assigned before the `space_attack.swf` is loaded?

Comment: yes I am I have no clue whats wrong.

Comment: Hmm... May be you loading an swf from other domain?

Comment: Nope both are on the same domain.